# Bill File Formatter Project in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

This is my first question in StackOverflow so I will try to do my best and hope to get some answers.

I'm currently part of an application development team, in which we receive a flat file with a header and a body of data, and we have to format it with some business logic and then write it into another flat file, with the specific format the company asks. This will be the bill for the client.

I want to know which way I should face this design. I was thinking of a simple Job with a step that reads the file and somehow stores the header and the body in different classes. An item processor to do all the business logic, and the item writer to write down the bill. I want to use listeners, validation, reports and logging, as well as multiple threads/parallel processing for better performance in production.

Having all this into account, how would you face this project? Every idea is welcome.

The input file is something like this:

```
01.01.2017|SUBDCOBR|12:21:23|01/12/2016|31/12/2016
01.01.2017|12345678231234|0002342434|BORGIA RUBEN|27-32548987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,01
01.01.2017|12345673201234|2342434|ALVAREZ ESTHER|27-32533987-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,02
01.01.2017|12345673201234|0002342434|LOPEZ LUCRECIA|27-32553387-9|FA|A|2062-
00010443/444/445|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
01.01.2017|12345672301234|0002342434|SILVA JESUS|27-32558657-9|NC|A|2062-
00010443|142,12|30/08/2017|142,12
```

Here is some of the code i tried, CabeceraFacturacion is the header and DetalleFacturacion is the body. I tried to make a reader for DetalleFacturacion and skip the first line, to treat it later in skippedLineCallback. However, i don't know what to write in handleLine() :

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<DetalleFacturacion> readerDetalleFacturacion(){

    FlatFileItemReader<DetalleFacturacion> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();

    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("inputFile.txt"));

    DefaultLineMapper<DetalleFacturacion> detalleLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizerDet = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|"); 
    tokenizerDet.setNames(new String[] {"fechaEmision", "tipoDocumento", "letra", "nroComprobante",  
                                "nroCliente", "razonSocial", "cuit", "montoNetoGP", "montoNetoG3",
                                "montoExento", "impuestos", "montoTotal"});

    LineCallbackHandler skippedLineCallback = new LineCallbackHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleLine(String line) {

            DefaultLineMapper<CabeceraFacturacion> cabeceraLineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();
            DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizerCab = new DelimitedLineTokenizer("|");
            // Maybe?? reader.setLineMapper(customLineMapper) or PatternMatchingCompositeLineMapper ??

        }
    };


    detalleLineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizerDet);
    detalleLineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new DetalleFieldSetMapper());
    detalleLineMapper.afterPropertiesSet();


    return reader;
}

@Bean
public Job jobFormateador() throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("jobFormateador")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(step1())
                .build();


}

@Bean
public Step step1() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<DetalleFacturacion, DetalleFacturacion> chunk(10)
            .reader(readerDetalleFacturacion())
            .writer(writerDetalleFact())
            .build();
}
```

How can I read and validate only the header and save it's content in CabeceraFacturacion class, and then read and validate only the body and save it's content in DetalleFacturacion class? Both of these then written to the same file, the bill itself.

Thank you everyone!!

Comment: Try to post here what you have already done. It´s easier for people who would like to help you.

Comment: I'm basically stuck and don't have much to show. i don't know the best way to process this file for what i want. i need to read the header and body separately, for different processing. Also, i can't decide which path to take in terms of coding. I don't know if it's best to do nested jobs.. or 1 job with different flows, or just 1 job with 1 step, and one itemReader, ItemProcessor and ItemWriter.

Comment: Describe the input file. I don´t know what is the header and what is the body of the file content.

Comment: There, i made an update. tokenizer.setNames would be the attributes of the body data. The header data is different and has no correlation with the rest of the file.